# How to preserve GTK look & feel in Java using sudo

Tags: java, linux, gtk, environment-variables, sudo

Often when you need to run some Java installers, you just do something like this:

```
$ sudo netbeans-8.1-linux.sh
```

And unfortunately this switches your nice, native GTK look & feel to some ugly, default Metal theme.

You can test it with this sample class:

```
// laf.java
import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class laf {
    public static void main(java.lang.String[] args) {
        try {
            System.out.println(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
}
```

And some output:

```
$ javac laf.java
$ java laf
com.sun.java.swing.plaf.gtk.GTKLookAndFeel
$ sudo java laf
javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel
```

This is how it looks using `sudo`:

[image: Standard Metal there on while using sudo with Java]

Answer (score 1):

To properly fix this behavior, you can add a sudoers file:

```
vim /etc/sudoers.d/20_keep_java_laf
```

with contents:

```
Defaults env_keep+=GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
```

This will be cause `UIManager#getSystemLookAndFeelClassName()` to resolve desktop, nice, GTK look & feel.

Now it is fixed:

[image: After fix to sudoers]

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to pass on the environmental variables using a `sudo` switch per http://askubuntu.com/questions/70534/what-are-the-differences-between-su-sudo-s-sudo-i-sudo-su?