# Have script detect gnome session

Tags: java, sudo, environment, gnome, gnome-terminal

I have a `makeself` script which I expect to be run as root; It's a desktop installer.

At the end of the script, the software which was recently installed to the filesystem tries to launch in user-space.

This works well using `sudo -u $(logname) /path/to/application` (or alternately [`sudo -u $SUDO_USER ...` in Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/a/849469/412004)) however a critical environmental variable from the user is missing:

```
GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
```

I need `GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID` because the child process belongs to Java and Java uses this environmental variable for detecting the [GtkLookAndFeel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34017981/3196753).

However attempts to use [`sudo -i`](https://askubuntu.com/a/547188/412004) have failed.

From some basic tests, the `GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID` doesn't appear to be a natural environmental variable when this users logs in.  For example, if I `CTRL+ALT+F1` to a terminal, `env |grep GNOME` yields nothing whereas `XTerm` and `gnome-terminal` both yield `GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID`.

How can I get a hold of this `GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID` variable from within the installer script without requiring users to pass something such as the `-E` parameter to the `sudo` command?

Note, although [`GtkLookAndFeel`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html#commandLine) is the primary look and feel for Linux, I prefer not to hard-code the [`export JAVA_OPTS`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33736268/3196753) either, I prefer to continue to fallback onto Oracle's detection techniques for support, longevity and scalability reasons.

**Update:** In Ubuntu, `GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID` lives in `/usr/share/upstart/sessions/xsession-init.conf`

```
 initctl set-env --global GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID=this-is-deprecated
```

Which leads to using `initctl get-env` to retrieve it.  Unfortunately this does not help within a new `sudo` shell, nor does any (optimistic) attempt at `dbus-launch`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out this is a two-step process...

1. Read the user's `UPSTART_SESSION` environmental variables from `/proc/$pid/environ`
2. Then `export UPSTART_SESSION` and call `initctl --user get-env GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID`

To make this a bit more scalable to other variables, I've wrapped this into a bash helper function.  This function should assist fetching other user-environment variables as well.  **Word of caution, it won't work if the variable's value has a space in the name.**

In the below example, only `UPSTART_SESSION` and `GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID` are required to answer the question.

Once `sudo_env` is called, the next call to `sudo -u ...` must be changed to `sudo -E -u ...`.  The `-E` will import the newly exported variables for use by a child process.

```
# Provide user environmental variables to the sudo environment
function sudo_env() {
    userid="$(logname 2>/dev/null || echo $SUDO_USER)"
    pid=$(ps aux |grep "^$userid" |grep "dbus-daemon" | grep "unix:" |awk '{print $2}')
    # Replace null delimiters with newline for grep
    envt=$(cat "/proc/$pid/environ" |tr '\0' '\n')

    # List of environmental variables to use; adjust as needed
    # UPSTART_SESSION must come before GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
    exports=( "UPSTART_SESSION" "DISPLAY" "DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS" "XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP" "GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID" )

    for i in "${exports[@]}"; do
        # Re-set the variable within this session by name
        # Careful, this technique won't yet work with spaces
        if echo "$envt" | grep "^$i=" > /dev/null 2>&1; then
            eval "$(echo "$envt" | grep "^$i=")" > /dev/null 2>&1
            export $i > /dev/null 2>&1
        elif initctl --user get-env $i > /dev/null 2>&1; then
            eval "$i=$(initctl --user get-env $i)" > /dev/null 2>&1
            export $i > /dev/null 2>&1
        fi

        echo "$i=${!i}"
    done
}
```

Comment: I'd like to specifically mention @dyorgio's help on this.  He provided the `/proc/$pid/environ` logic to me on another help forum which is 50% of the above solution.  Thanks!

Comment: @dyorgio, FYI, `GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID` seems to no longer be readable on Ubuntu 18.04 by using the `cat "/proc/$pid/environ" |tr '\0' '\n'` trick.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a new file on /etc/sudoers.d with this content:

```
Defaults env_keep+=GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID
```

But, there is a problem, if you already are inside sudo, it will not been read again.

So, the complete solution is use sudo inside your script to create this file and then execute your command in another sudo:

```
#!/bin/bash
# ignore sudo
if [[ -z $SUDO_USER ]]; then
    #save current dir
    DIR="$(pwd)"
    #generate random string (file name compatible)
    NEW_UUID=$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc 'a-zA-Z0-9' | fold -w 32 | head -n 1)
    #create env_keep file
    sudo -i -- <<EOF0
        echo "Defaults env_keep+=GNOME_DESKTOP_SESSION_ID" > /etc/sudoers.d/"$NEW_UUID"_keep_java_laf
    EOF0
    sudo -u YOUR_USER -i -- <<EOF
        #go to original directory
        cd "$DIR"
        #execute your java command
        java YOUR_COMMAND
    EOF
    #clean file
    sudo rm -f /etc/sudoers.d/"$NEW_UUID"_keep_java_laf
else
    echo "sudo not allowed!";exit 1;
fi
```

Comment: Thanks!  How would this work in combination with `sudo -u foo`?

Comment: The logic helps but it doesn't fix the problem.  The proposed fix doesn't seem to help unless I comment out the `rm -f` line, hard code the file name and run the installer a second time.  This is an installer that already has root permissions and itself is already inside a `sudo` call.  On a side note... according to the sudoers `README`, you should use `umask 0337` before calling echo, but it seems to be getting set too late.   The installer is already launched with `sudo` and the environmental variable is lost (I assume).